# how to display JSON data(Parent-Child-Grandchild) in three separate Divs using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```js
ver data = [
    {"id": 1,"parent": 0,"name": "Parent"},
    {"id": 2,"parent": 1,"name": "Child"},
    {"id": 3,"parent": 1,"name": "Child"},
    {"id": 4,"parent": 2,"name": "GrandChild"},
    {"id": 5,"parent": 2,"name": "GrandChild"},
    {"id": 6,"parent": 3,"name": "GrandChild"},
    {"id": 7,"parent": 3,"name": "GrandChild"},
    {"id": 8,"parent": 5,"name": "Great-GrandChild"},
    {"id": 9,"parent": 5,"name": "Great-GrandChild"},
    {"id": 10,"parent": 6,"name": "Great-GrandChild"},
    {"id": 11,"parent": 6,"name": "Great-GrandChild"},
    {"id": 12,"parent": 7,"name": "Great-GrandChild"},
    {"id": 13,"parent": 7,"name": "Great-GrandChild"}
]
```

**how to display JSON data(Parent-Child-Grandchild) in three separate Divs using Jquery or Javascript. also click to change categories (onclick parent in middle div and show child in right div)**

```html
<div class="w-100 d-flex">
            <div class="eq_width align-self-center left_side">
                <span class="label">Parent</span>
            </div>

            <div class="vl"></div>
            <div class="eq_width align-self-center middle_side">
                <span class="label">Child</span>
                <span class="label">Child</span>
            </div>

            <div class="vl"></div>
            <div class="eq_width align-self-center right_side">
                <span class="label">GrandChild</span>
                <span class="label">GrandChild</span>
                <span class="label">GrandChild</span>
                <span class="label">GrandChild</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `ver` key to define your data I correct it as this:

```
var data = [
    {"id": 1,"parent": 0,"name": "Parent"},
    {"id": 2,"parent": 1,"name": "Child"},
    {"id": 3,"parent": 1,"name": "Child"},
    {"id": 4,"parent": 2,"name": "GrandChild"},
    {"id": 5,"parent": 2,"name": "GrandChild"},
    {"id": 6,"parent": 3,"name": "GrandChild"},
    {"id": 7,"parent": 3,"name": "GrandChild"},
];
```

First I defined a function to get any of these rows by it's id as bellow.

```
let getById = (_id, _data) =>
{
    let r = _data.find(x => x.id === _id);

    if(r == undefined)
        return false;

    return r;
}
```

Then I defined another function to add records based on their type (`parent`, `child` or `grandchile`)

```
let add = (row,_data) =>
{
    let _class;
    let type;

    if(row.parent == "0")
        _class = "left_side";
    else
    {
        let parent = getById(row.parent, _data);

        if(parent === false)
            return false;

        if(parent.parent == "0")
            _class = "middle_side";
        else
        {
            _class = "right_side";

            if(getById(parent.parent, _data) === false)
                return false;
        }
    }

    $("." + _class).append(`<span class="label">${row.name}</span>`);
}
```

Now you can add any of the records based on their type easily like this

```
$.each(data,(index,value)=>{
    if(add(value,data) === false)
    {
        // wrong data. show some error!
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help! It's working perfectly. only issue is right_side shows all childs (even child of child) i want only 3 levels of data then change onclick.

Comment: Glad I could help! I checked my codes again and I get the result right! My right side only shows `child`s not `grandchild`! @Dhanu

Comment: I don't understand your second part of your question! You mean you want to show only three of each type then when user clicks on a button like *more*, all of type become visible?

Comment: if user click on `grandchild` (if it have child) then `grandchild` shows in middle div and their child shows in right div...I update JSON data for better understanding

Comment: when user click any `label` then `label` shows in middle div and it's sub-category(child) shows in right div.....it short all shows dynamically....i hope you understand